# Ember QUnit moduleFor (testing) adapter retrieving Store

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I am writing test for my custom DS.RESTAdapter, which uses our own SDK as transporter instead of ajax calls. Now, I want to test the adapters find, findAll, findQuery ... functions which require me to pass an instance of store as a parameter. 
For example:

```
findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken){...}
```

To be able to test this, i need to pass "store" param which is not available in moduleFor in ember-qunit (unlike in moduleForModel where you can access store via this.store within the test instance).

Is there another way to gain access to the current instance of store?

Thanks.

Edit:

I solved this by creating mocks for both, store and type. 
You can create a store instance by:

```
var store = DS.Store.create({
    adapter: @subject
})
```

And a mock for type, just as an ordinary object with required properties for the test.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can directly using `moduleFor`, but using just `module` you should be able to access it from the app instance. You can use `App.__container__.lookup('store:main')` to get back the instance of the ember-data store.

Comment: Yes, but that would require me to create a new App instance, which I wanted to avoid. 
I solved by creating mocks for both, store and type. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Any chance your code is online somewhere? Looking to achieve the same thing and could save a lot of digging. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock this method (for instance, using [Sinon plugin for QUnit](http://sinonjs.org/qunit/)). Another solution for accessing the store (but I'm not sure it will work in your case) which helped me to access store from the global namespace is using `setup` and `teardown` methods:

```
  setup: function () {
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function () {
    App.reset();
  }
```

Comment: Actually I ended up creating mocks for both "store" and "type". Thanks for the answer though.